# Problem with Positioning of Page Number after \newgeometry

Tags: positioning, page-numbering, fancyhdr, geometry, adjustwidth

I am using \usepackage{fancyhdr} for my headings and the positioning of the page numbering.
I am reporting several graphs on one page and since I want to make these graphs big enough, I have used \newgeometry to adjust the margins. However, now the page numbering is not at the bottom anymore and not centered. I tried \adjustwidth but I did not make it work.
Do you guys have any idea how I can both adjust my margins and keep the position of the page number identical as before?
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance for your time and your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=35mm,top=35mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{epsfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amsbsy,amssymb,calc,longtable,url,rotating,graphicx,graphics,lscape,tabularx,xtab,eurosym}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize, labelformat=empty, position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\chaptermark{}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\section{1}
Example page with correct position of page number

\newgeometry{left=20mm,right=25mm}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Threshold in 2004}
\vspace*{1em}
\centering
    \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{100pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Full Sample}}}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
    \caption*{Eligible} \vspace{-0.6em}%
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.5cm, width=\textwidth]{Graph_1.pdf} 
    \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.01cm}\vspace{-0.5em}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
    \caption*{Not Eligible} \vspace{-0.6em}%
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.5cm, width=\textwidth]{Graph_2.pdf} 
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{100pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sub-Sample}}}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.3cm, width=\textwidth]{Graph_3.pdf} 
    \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.01cm}\vspace{-0.5em}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.3cm, width=\textwidth]{Graph_4.pdf} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace*{-0.25cm}
\caption*{\footnotesize The graphs shows XXX...}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing   `\fancyfootoffset{0pt}` after`\newgeometry`  causes `fancyhdr` to recalculate the header and footer.

It is not needed after `\restoregeometry`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=35mm,top=35mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{epsfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amsbsy,amssymb,calc,longtable,url,rotating,graphicx,graphics,lscape,tabularx,eurosym}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize, labelformat=empty, position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \chaptermark{}
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \section{1}
    Example page with correct position of page number
    
    \newgeometry{left=20mm,right=25mm}
    \fancyfootoffset{0pt} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Threshold in 2004}
        \vspace*{1em}
        \centering
        \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{100pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Full Sample}}}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
            \caption*{Eligible} \vspace{-0.6em}%
            \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.01cm}\vspace{-0.5em}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
            \caption*{Not Eligible} \vspace{-0.6em}%
            \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{100pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sub-Sample}}}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
            \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.3cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.01cm}\vspace{-0.5em}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth} 
            \includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.3cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
        \end{subfigure}
        \vspace*{-0.25cm}
        \caption*{\footnotesize The graphs shows XXX...}
    \end{figure}
    \restoregeometry

    Some text.
    
\end{document}
```